# A property of the Hilbert transform involving the cotangent function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

A lemma of a paper by T. Elgindi and I.-J. Jeong (Arch. Rational Mech. Anal. 235 (2020) 1763–1817, Lemma 2.2) states the following:

Let $g(z)=\operatorname{sgn}(z)k(|z|^\alpha)$ with $k$ smooth and $k(0)=0$. Then
$$
\lim_{z\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{|z|^\alpha}[Hg(z)-Hg(0)]=\cot\left(\frac{\alpha\pi}{2}\right)k'(0)
$$

I don't understand some steps of the proof; namely, the replacement of the function $k$ by $|z|^\alpha k'(0)$ in the Hilbert transform. Could someone please help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Since $k(0)=0$, $|z|^{\alpha } k'(0)$ is the leading term in the Taylor expansion around $z=0$.

Comment: Yes, but how does that work with the definition of principal value.

Comment: I don't understand the remark - expanding the integrand doesn't have a direct connection to the principal value. Integration happens later, the expansion is initially just a manipulation of the integrand.